# diamondback repository (Overo FE COM - Ubuntu natty)

Tags: ros, gumstix, ubuntu, ubuntu-natty, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need help. I installed Ubuntu 11.04 on a SD card and booted on a Overo FE COM. It worked perfectly. I have access to internet and everything else. Now, I am trying to install a basic package from ROS (no GUI tools). Based on the tutorials that I found, I was supposed to install the diamondback version of ROS. So, I followed the instructions from the website wiki.ros.org/diamondback/installation/Ubuntu,  but it didn't work. I tried to install from source (rosinstall) but I had no success either. Looks like the repository (http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=ros-base&overlay=no) is not on. Does anyone know why the rep is not working? Is there a different one that I can use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199548/diamondback-repository-(overo-fe-com---ubuntu-natty)/) by [Jhielson](https://answers.ros.org/users/21124/jhielson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Diamondback is no longer supported, and hasn't been supported for several years.

The tool you're trying to use was taken offline because it was too slow and prone to errors. It has been replaced by rosinstall_generator, but rosinstall_generator only supports ROS versions Groovy and newer.

You should look for a newer version of Ubuntu and a newer version of ROS.

Once I get the DNS for my packages server fixed, [Hydro](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UbuntuARM) on Ubuntu 12.04 and [Indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM) on Ubuntu 14.04 are reported to work on the gumstix boards.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jhielson](https://answers.ros.org/users/21124/jhielson/) on 2014-12-16**:
Thank you very much. I'm gonna look for those images. I found the last release of Linaro, but to another boards.